# glob() gives "realloc(): invalid pointer" when using GLOB_APPEND as the flag

Tags: c, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Good day. I am trying to retrieve path names using multiple filters.

```
glob_t globbuf;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   char*currentFilter = concat(Workdir, fileNameFilter[i]);
   int result;
   printf("This is the current filter %s", currentFilter)
   result = glob(currntFilter,GLOB_APPEND, NULL, &globbuf)
}
```

When ./a.out is entered, it goes through the first iteration just fine until it hits the glob() function.
terminal prints out:

realloc(): invalid pointer

While writing this, I think I found is that glob does not have anything to append? Is this why I am getting this error?

I write mostly in C#, is this similar to a null reference exception?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`globbuf` is uninitialized. You can only use `GLOB_APPEND` with a `glob_t` initialized by a previous successful call to `glob`. So for example you could do `i==0 ? 0 : GLOB_APPEND` instead of `GLOB_APPEND`. But you should also add some checking of return value, etc. since the usage error would come back if the first call failed, rather than just hard-coding an assumption that the first call succeeds.